# How to include the symbol $ within a url?

Tags: urls

I need to write a url including a character which seems a command , $

the entire command is :

```
\item URL - this is set as "\nolinkurl{http://localhost:9200/\$*/pcap/}";
```

but this produce:

> URL - this is set as " http://localhost:9200/\protect\T1\
>   textdollar*/pcap/ "

how can I avoid part "\protected\T1\textdollar" ?

Comment: Use `\usepackage{url,hyperref} \urldef\myURL\nolinkurl{http://localhost:9200/$*/pcap/}` which allows you to place `\myURL` where you need it.

Comment: Isn't just `$` instead of `\$` what you want? Special characters in URLs need not being escaped (if the `\url` command, or `\nolinkurl`, is in normal running text).